# Resize to scale multiple layers at once in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have approx 20 layers in illustrator (a world map with layers for capital city names, small city names, rivers, oceans, etc). I want to increase the size of this map, so I need to increase the size of every layer without distortion. I have tried to Select all - group - transform, but all layers disappear off the artboard and are bigger than the dimensions I typed into W x H boxes. Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand this. You should be able to select all and scale. There's no need to group. I think you may need to provide more detailed information.

Comment: Not sure why you would need them all in a group, but if you play with your layers palette a bit, you can put a layer within another layer. This will allow you to group them and keep the parts separate. I don't have much time at the moment to explain this more or to do a proper answer, but hopefully this might point you in a direction that will help, or someone else might be able to expand on this idea. I'll try to come back later and flesh out this thought more.

Comment: Hi Scott, first I increased my artboard size to accomodate the larger size layers I want. I then select all on active artboard - enter my new required width as 812mm (chain link symbol open) - then press shift to enter Height dimension, but before I can enter this the progress bar appears and when completed the width has changed to 3553mm. New to illustrator so may be wrong!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe *should* work fine (although you don't need <kbd>Shift</kbd> if the chain icon is active).

With the chain active, you do **not** want to enter both width and height. You only want to enter 1 dimension. The chain icon tells Illustrator to **automatically calculate** the other dimension **proportionally**.

So, you would enter a width and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That's all.

If you want to non-proportionally scale everything, unclick the chain icon and then enter a width and height.

It sounds as if you are ticking the chain icon (keep proportional) then entering a width, then entering a height. Since the height is the last dimension entered, Illustrator is making the width *proportional* to *that* height.

Comment: Hi Scott, I follow thanks. However, I get the same problem, The original size is 419 x 209mm. When I replace 419 with my required 812mm and hit enter the progress bar is transforming objects then the final dimensions show 4310 x 2534mm. It seems like i am doing everything correct. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Update: Scott as per above, I just turned on show rulers and some of the layers I resized seem to be correctly resized accordinf to the ruler, howver the dimension are still showing 4310 x 2534. Also, when resized they go off the artboard. I ddragged then back on but not all came across?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue specifically so I don't know what to tell you. It must be due to the artwork in this case. It's possible that raster effects (shadows/glows etc) could account for the odd numbers, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will play around with it. It does seem a bit strange but I will get there. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Realize that the artboard *never* restricts content. It's just a floating "plane" behind things. Objects aren't bound to the artboard boundaries. So things going off the artboard isn't really a technical *issue*.

Comment: Thanks Scott. FYI, I restarted illustrator and did it again. it worked but I had to group all objects first as it would not resize some parts of layers. Now I cannot ungroup!! LOL always something!

Answer (score 0):

Select the layers you want to transform, go to Object Menu > Transform > Transform Each option.